# Autoprefixer doesn't add vendor prefixes

Tags: gulp, postcss, autoprefixer

Here is the task :

```
gulp.task('process-css', function(){
  return gulp.src('./app/css/scss/main.scss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(postcss([postcssMixins, postcssCalc, postcssSimpleVars, postcssColor, postcssExtend, postcssNesting, autoprefixer])) 
    .on('error', function(errorHandler){
      console.log(errorHandler.toString());
      this.emit('end');
    })
    .pipe(concatCSS('style.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/css/'));
});
```

I'm using the standard autoprefixer plugin (not gulp-autoprefixer, which basically did the same thing on the last task-runner I was using), but it only adds the -webkit- prefix. I tried it with properties like clip-path and display: flex, but it doesn't add the vendor prefixes. I tried changing the line to

```
 .pipe(postcss([
 postcssMixins, postcssCalc, postcssSimpleVars,
 postcssColor, postcssExtend, postcssNesting,
 autoprefixer([{browsers: '> 0%'}]))
```

but that didn't work either, what is wrong with it?

-- Fixed -- 
I think some of the other plugins is using autoprefixer too and it was messing with my configs. The way I fixed it was to add this at the bottom of my package.json file

```
"browserslist": [
    "> 0%",
    "last 2 versions"
  ]
```

Add it with a comma after the last curly brace for your devDependencies

Answer (score 1):

Flex is very well supported so probably you don't need it anymore (autoprefixer don't add prefixes to the property by default anymore for a while — check can I use). But if you really need it you can do the steps:

- Let's say you have `css` folder and `dist` folder for yours styles in your working directory.
- create **.browserslistrc** file at the root of the working directory and put `last 4 versions` in it.
- run `postcss css/styles.css -u autoprefixer -o dist/styles.css` in your terminal